# Удаление класса по повторному клику

Tags: javascript

Почему не срабатывает `event.target.classList.toggle('style')` и при повторном клике на элемент класс 'style' не удаляется? Как реализовать?

```js
const wrapper = document.querySelector('.wrap');

function handleEvent(event) {
  if (event.target && event.target.classList == 'string') {
      event.target.classList.toggle('style')
  }
};

wrapper.addEventListener('click', handleEvent);
```

```css
.style {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="string">Один</div>
  <div class="string">Два</dib>
</div>
```

Comment: ну так посмотрите чем у вас является `event.target.classList` или что там хранится каждый раз и придите к каким-то выводам. Отладка вам в помощь

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const wrapper = document.querySelector('.wrap');

function handleEvent(event) {
  if (event.target && event.target.classList.contains('string')) {
    event.target.classList.toggle('style');
  }
};

wrapper.addEventListener('click', handleEvent);
```

```css
.style {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="string">Один</div>
  <div class="string">Два</div>
</div>
```